# How to upload multiple images (image List) in Firebase Storage

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

I am trying to store the images List in Firebase Storage in this code but it shows this type of error

**" ' type '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String' "**

I pick the image in this code.

```
 List<dynamic> imageFileList = [];

  File? _selectedCoverImage;

//image picker method

  Future _pickeImageFromGallery() async {
    final image = await ImagePicker()
        .pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 70);
    if (image == null) return;
    setState(() {
      imageFileList.add(File(image.path));
    });
  }
```

and it is Firebase code.

```
   final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User? user = auth.currentUser;


 static Future<void> uploadOtherImages(List<dynamic> imagePaths) async {
 
    final Reference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child
      ('otherImages');

    for (String imagePath in imagePaths) {
      final file = File(imagePath);

      try {
        await storageRef.child('$user.uid/${DateTime.now()}.jpg').putFile(file);
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error uploading image: $e');
      }



    }
  }
```

and other necessary libraries or inital code already setup.

I try to upload images but it shows an error, "'_File' is not a subtype of type 'String' "

I want to upload an [image]image of this type.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the provided method; it is optimized and well-coded.

```
 Future<void> uploadOtherImages(List<File> images) async {
      final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      final User? user = auth.currentUser;
      final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('images');
      final tasks = <Future<void>>[];
    
      await Future.forEach(images, (File image) async {
        final fileRef = storageRef.child('${user.uid}/image_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.${image.path.split('.').last}');
        final task = fileRef.putFile(image);
        tasks.add(task);
      });
    
      final results = await Future.wait(tasks);
    
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if (results[i] != null) {
          print('Image $i failed to upload: ${results[i]}');
        }
      }
    }
```

*Your mistake was here.*

```
for (String imagePath in imagePaths) {}
```

In this loop, `imagePaths` is a `List<File>`, which is derived from the `imageFileList` variable. Here's the issue: you are iterating over `imagePaths` and using `imagePath` as a `string`. This means that you are attempting to extract a `String` from a `List<File>`.